# LSTM class, got error: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_shape'

Tags: class, lstm, keyword, init

```
class LSTM:

    scaler_y_train= MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
    scaler_x_train= MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
    scaler_forecast= MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))

    def __init__(self, filename, seq_len, forecast_size):
        self._filename= filename
        self._seq_len= seq_len
        self._forecast_size= forecast_size
        self.model= Sequential()


    def load_y_train(self):
        raw_data_values= self._filename.values
        raw_data= self._filename
        print('Initializing the data loading...')
        forecast_out_variable= math.ceil(len(raw_data_values)* self._forecast_size)
        forecast_out_fixed= None

        print('Creating y_train...')
        y= raw_data.iloc[forecast_out_variable:].values
        len_y= len(y)
        data_windows_y= []
        for i in range(len_y - self._seq_len):
            data_windows_y.append(y[i: i + self._seq_len])
        data_windows_y= np.array(data_windows_y).astype(float)
        y_train= data_windows_y[:, -1, [0]]
        return print(y_train.shape), y_train

    def load_x_train(self):
        raw_data_values= self._filename.values
        raw_data= self._filename
        print('Initializing the data loading...')
        forecast_out_variable= math.ceil(len(raw_data_values)* self._forecast_size)
        forecast_out_fixed= None

        print('Creating x_train...')
        x= raw_data.iloc[:-forecast_out_variable].values
        len_x= len(x)
        data_windows_x= []
        for i in range(len_x - self._seq_len):
            data_windows_x.append(x[i: i + self._seq_len])
        data_windows_x= np.array(data_windows_x).astype(float)
        x_train= data_windows_x[:, :-1]
        return x_train

    def load_x_forecast(self):
        raw_data_values= self._filename.values
        raw_data= self._filename
        print('Initializing the data loading...')
        forecast_out_variable= math.ceil(len(raw_data_values)* self._forecast_size)
        forecast_out_fixed= None

        print('Creating x_train...')
        x_forecast = raw_data.iloc[:-forecast_out_variable].values
        len_x_forecast= len(x_forecast)
        data_windows_x= []
        for i in range(len_x_forecast - self._seq_len):
            data_windows_x.append(x_forecast[i: i + self._seq_len])
        data_windows_x= np.array(data_windows_x).astype(float)
        xx_forecast= data_windows_x[:, :-1]
        return print(xx_forecast.shape), xx_forecast

    def build_model(self):
        x_train= self.load_x_train()
        x_train= np.array(x_train).reshape(1050,49,2).astype(float)
        print(x_train.shape)
        print('Model starting compiling...')
        start= time.time()

        self.model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[-1]), 
        return_sequences=True))
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        self.model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=False))
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        self.model.add(Dense(1, activation = "linear"))
        self.model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
        end= time.time()
        print ('model compiled in: ' +str((end-start)*1000)+ ' ms')
        return model, print(model.summary())




lstm_01= LSTM(ms_unreal, 50, 0.1)
print(lstm_01.load_x_forecast())
print(lstm_01.load_y_train())
print(lstm_01.load_x_train())
print(lstm_01.build_model(model))
```

Type error is **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_shape',
I do not know how to made it work as im calling correctly the libraries. I searched the problem online but im not able to understand the issue. 
The code is a class named LSTM where basically the first function are finalized to get the train and test data, while the last one (in which there is the issue) is to initialize the LSTM keras model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class is called LSTM and you call a function from Keras called LSTM. Try renaming your class My_LSTM or some variant. Otherwise you won't be able to call your class without overwriting the Keras implementation.