# defining the input shape of LSTM in Kears

Tags: keras, lstm, multivariate-time-series

I'm trying to build LSTM using keras. but it doesn't accept to pass the input shape or any other other parameters in the LSTM layer.
This is my code

```
def LSTM(structure):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(20 ,input_shape=(data["X_train"].shape[1],data["X_train"].shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dense(units=1, activation = 'linear'))
    return model
```

and this is the error :

```
---> 73      model.add(LSTM(20 ,input_shape=(data["X_train"].shape[1],data["X_train"].shape[2]), return_sequences=True))

TypeError: LSTM() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_shape'
```

and the same for the return_sequences paramater.
If I cannot pass the input shape here, where should I define the input shape for the LSTM network?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error. All I have done is changeing the name of function as the name of function is the same as the LSTM keyword.
this link explains more
[LSTM class, got error: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_shape'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59035050/lstm-class-got-error-typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument)